# How can I programmatically retrieve a loaded project in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-sdk

I want to create an hour counter to monitor my development time on a project. I want the time to increase whenever a certain project is active in Visual Studio 2008.

Can I progammatically find out which *.csproj file is currently active in VS2008?

Comment: when you start turn your wrist over. note time from mechanism on wrist. when finished, repeat. calculate difference.

Comment: snidery aside, i would be interested in your project, should you ever figure out how! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the loaded solution via the `DTE.Solution` property, and the active document via `DTE.ActiveDocument`.  There isn't really an "active project" because you never really activate projects, you only open solutions (which can contain multiple projects) and files (which happen to be in projects).

I suspect for a time-tracking requirement, getting the current solution would probably suffice.  However, if you need to specifically distinguish between projects in the solution, you can do this using `DTE.ActiveDocument.ProjectItem.ContainingProject`.